# How to visualize OpenGL ES 2.0 Fragment Shaders

Tags: opengl-es

I am trying to wrap my brain around OpenGL ES shaders:

Vertex:
So Vertex shaders are handling the vertices for all objects/mesh in a glDrawXXX. Like if you have 2 triangle meshes forming a square/box. This makes it possible to move around each vertex, set colors, and more?

Fragment:
Is it everything in between the vertices?

How to get a mental visualization of this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you just asking how the different shader stages work, or is it something else?

Comment: I guess - I can't seem to see the different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most straightforward, simple case;

The vertex shader is called for every vertex of a primitive. 100 Vertices = 100 invocations of the active vertex shader. A latter stage then generates triangles from the vertices.

Now, for each triangle generated by the vertex shader, it gets rasterized to generate fragments (i.e. potential pixels). The rasterizer linearly interpolates between each vertex of a triangle to generate the fragment locations of the triangle. Where you are getting confused is probably thinking that the fragment shader is called 1-to-1 along with the vertex shader. Nope, there can be zero to millions of fragments generated - it depends upon how big (visually) the resulting triangle is going to be. The fragment shader is called on each fragment generated. it depends on the vertices output by the vertex shader.

If a triangle is far away from the viewpoint, it may be a few fragments. If it's close to the screen it can take up the whole viewport.